# Twisted on Python3: Install fails with a series of "File Not Found" errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, twisted

I am having exactly the problem described here:

https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/6539#comment:12

However, the ticket is closed, and everybody seems to think that a huge subset of Twisted now runs on Python 3.

When I install Twisted with Python 3, the errors listed on the ticket are emitted, and I then experience the following:

```
In [1]: import twisted

In [2]: dir(twisted)
Out[2]: 
['Version',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__file__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__le__',
 '__loader__',
 '__lt__',
 '__name__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__spec__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__version__',
 '_checkRequirements',
 '_version',
 'deprecatedModuleAttribute',
 'python',
 'version']

In [3]: from twisted import scripts
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 from twisted import scripts

ImportError: cannot import name 'scripts'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The comment you link to says that there are some harmless errors, but implies that it otherwise works.  If that is the problem you are having then... yes, that's expected?  Twisted is not fully ported to python 3.  Perhaps you could be more specific about the observed vs. expected behavior?

Comment: Bonjour Glyph.  Thanks so much for the fast response.  I have added to my post to make the problem more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `twisted.scripts` module isn't ported yet.  You can see the full list of things which *have* been ported [here](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/twisted/python/dist3.py#L39).  [`twisted.scripts.twistd` is an "almostModule"](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/trunk/twisted/python/dist3.py#L380), which means it's pretty close; that would be a good place to try to start porting.